# is it better with past perfect continuous in this case

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

**I've been trying** to find this song since 2009. my dad played it and I recorded a clip from 0.59 to 1.01 and with the help of sound hound I finally found it!

Why not "I had been trying" because  his trying stopped when he found it, so the action is completed or can he change by I have finally found it.

Is "have been trying" grammatically correct in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

**I've *been trying to find this song since 2009*. My dad played it and I recorded a clip from it and with the help of sound hound I finally *found it*!**

- First, this is just internet speech.
- But it works.
- Speech occurs in "bursts"
- The sentences are not even together.

I've *been trying to find this song since 2009.* = The guy says this in the present.

This is not written text where the one action strictly precedes another.

[If you are a French speaker, it's fine to say: je cherchais x depuis 2009 [un dire au présent], and not: j'avais cherché x depuis 2009.

Now, ***if the guy were writing a blog post, it would be better to write:***

- I'd been trying to find this song since 2009 and I finally found it!

Answer (score 0):

Present Perfect Progressive can be used for a thing that has recently finished.

This tense can also mean that the process is still going on, but from the context you provided we can understand that it is not:

> with the help of sound hound I finally found it!

In this case, Past Simple is clearly about a finished event in the past, and because it's the same event as in the first sentence, Present Perfect Progressive is OK. The focus of Perfect Progressive is that the action was long and took a considerable amount of time.